# Api to delete route of spring actuator gateway not working?

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-gateway, dynamic-routing

I have built an gateway service and it worked perfectly. Now I want to delete some routes in that gateway, I use the API /actuator/gateway/routes/{route_id} with DELETE request as in the document of Spring, but it responses Not found Route by id, but when I use the API /actuator/gateway/routes/{route_id} with GET request, I got the routes.
Is there any wrong with the API of Spring?

Answer (score 0):

After delete you should call refresh.